# Jtable model change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change the table shown in the panel. but when I change the TableModel, the header part changes, the other parts do not change. When I click on the cells it starts to display. how can I solve this problem?

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL734.png)

```
public void tabloyuDoldur() {

    String dizim[][] = new String[planlist.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < planlist.size(); i++) {



        dizim[i] = new String[] { planlist.get(i).getId(), planlist.get(i).getOperation(),
                planlist.get(i).getName(), planlist.get(i).getE_rows(), planlist.get(i).getE_bytes(),
                planlist.get(i).getCost_cpu(), planlist.get(i).getE_time(), planlist.get(i).getPstart(),
                planlist.get(i).getPstop() };

        TableModel tabloModeli = new DefaultTableModel(dizim, new String[] { " Id ", "Operation", "Name", "E-Rows",
                "E-Bytes", "Cost (%CPU)", "E-Time","E-Temp", "Pstart", "Pstop" });




        table.setModel(tabloModeli);



    }
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cell_render_object);
```

other table model method

```
}

public void tabloyuDoldur(int selectedHashValue) {

    if (selectedHashValue == 0) {
        String dizim[][] = new String[avglist.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < avglist.size(); i++) {

            dizim[i] = new String[] { avglist.get(i).getSql_id(), avglist.get(i).getPlan_hash_value(),
                    avglist.get(i).getElapAvg(), avglist.get(i).getCpuAvg(), avglist.get(i).getIoAvg(),
                    avglist.get(i).getClusAvg(), avglist.get(i).getAppAvg(), avglist.get(i).getConcAvg(),
                    avglist.get(i).getPlsqlAvg() };
            TableModel tabloModeli = new DefaultTableModel(dizim, new String[] { "sql_id", "plan hash value",
                    "ELAP AVG", "CPU AVG", "I/O AVG", "CLUS AVG", "APP AVG", "CONC AVG", "PLSQL AVG" });
            table.setModel(tabloModeli);
        }
    } else {
        int i = selectedHashValue - 1;
        String dizim[][] = new String[1][];
        dizim[0] = new String[] { avglist.get(i).getSql_id(), avglist.get(i).getPlan_hash_value(),
                avglist.get(i).getElapAvg(), avglist.get(i).getCpuAvg(), avglist.get(i).getIoAvg(),
                avglist.get(i).getClusAvg(), avglist.get(i).getAppAvg(), avglist.get(i).getConcAvg(),
                avglist.get(i).getPlsqlAvg() };
        TableModel tabloModel = new DefaultTableModel(dizim, new String[] { "sql_id", "plan hash value",
                "ELAP AVG", "CPU AVG", "I/O AVG", "CLUS AVG", "APP AVG", "CONC AVG", "PLSQL AVG" });

        table.setModel(tabloModel);

    }

}
```

actually this problem is happening after the code I used to change the cell color.

```
    public class MyTableCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  public MyTableCellRender() {
  setOpaque(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
  boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

   String name = (String)value;

    String data=name.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    if(data.equals("TABLEACCESSFULL"))    
        setForeground(Color.red);
    else if(data.equals("MERGEJOINCARTESIAN"))
        setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    else  
        setForeground(Color.black);



   return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value, 
   isSelected,hasFocus,row, column);

   } }
```

Comment: if the other parts don't change then  I would say your data is the same. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And use hard coded data in the program since we won't have access to your real data. The point of the `MCVE` is to proof the concept works. Also, you cell renderer code is wrong. You should be invoking the `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` method as the first statement so you can reset the colors AFTER the default colors have already been set.

Comment: Still don't see a [mcve]. That is why you haven't received any help.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you for your interest @camickr

Answer (score 0):

String name = (String)value; the problem arises from this casting process. when you change it String name = String.valueOf(value);